# rails link_to on overlay div

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a div structured like so:

```
          <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <!-- Shot -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="shot shot-minimal">
                <div class="shot-preview">
                  <a class="img" href="shot-gallery.html"><img src="http://rwdtow.stdout.in/img/avatar-icon.png" alt=""></a>

                  <a class="text-overlay">
                      <span class="heading"><%= post.tite %></span>
                      <span class="desc"><%= post.shortdescription %></span>
                    <time datetime="2016-02-04 22:30">7 hours ago</time>
                  </a>
                </div>

                <div class="shot-detail">
                  <div class="shot-info">
                    <p><%= post.title %></p>
                  </div>

                  <ul class="shot-stats">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span>6.3k</span></li>
                    <li><a class="like" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span>1.2k</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Shot -->
          <% end %>
```

In the above div i have an overlay:

```
              <a class="text-overlay">
                  <span class="heading"><%= post.tite %></span>
                  <span class="desc"><%= post.shortdescription %></span>
                <time datetime="2016-02-04 22:30">7 hours ago</time>
              </a>
```

So i placed a link_to with the overlay, so the text overlays, the text is clickable:

```
              <%= link_to post, class:"text-overlay" do %>        
                  <span class="heading"><%= post.tite %></span>
                  <span class="desc"><%= post.shortdescription %></span>
                <time datetime="2016-02-04 22:30">7 hours ago</time>
              <% end %>
```

The overlay works correct, but when i click on it, it does not take me to the show action for the post. Heres how my final code looks:

```
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <!-- Shot -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="shot shot-minimal">
            <div class="shot-preview">
              <a class="img" href="shot-gallery.html"><img src="http://rwdtow.stdout.in/img/avatar-icon.png" alt=""></a>

              <%= link_to post, class:"text-overlay" do %>        
               <span class="heading"><%= post.tite %></span>
               <span class="desc"><%= post.shortdescription %></span>
               <time datetime="2016-02-04 22:30">7 hours ago</time>
              <% end %>
            </div>

            <div class="shot-detail">
              <div class="shot-info">
                <p><%= post.title %></p>
              </div>

              <ul class="shot-stats">
                <li><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span>6.3k</span></li>
                <li><a class="like" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span>1.2k</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Shot -->
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't comment because of my reputation. Can you provide me two more things?

1. Rendered HTML code in browser. You can get it by doing "Inspect Element" in browser.
2. JavaScript/JQuery/CoffeeScript associated with `$(".text-overlay")`. Remove `event.preventDefault()`. I have used JQuery Syntax. If you are using some other library then find syntax for the same and remove.